# catch urls with specific pattern and show specific content for them by plugin

Tags: plugins, pages, url-rewriting

I have written a *shortcode* in a *plugin* that shows some *items*.

my shortcode: *[showItems]*

now I put this shortcode in a page called *items*:

```
http://mywordpress_site.com/items
```

in this *shortcode* I only show 100 items per page and have a pagination. every page url must be in this pattern:

```
http://mywordpress_site.com/items/1/ // page 2
http://mywordpress_site.com/items/12/ // page 12
```

now I want to know how can I catch *urls* with this *pattern* from my *plugin* and show *related items* for this *url pattern*:

```
/items/$pageNumber/
```

Answer (score 0):

There might be other ways, but what I would so is create a rewrite rule in your .htaccess file, something like:

`RewriteRule ^items/([0-9]*) /items/?page=$1`

Now your user sees:
http://mywordpress_site.com/items/1/

But behind the scenes, your site sees:
http://mywordpress_site.com/items/?page=1

Then in your shortcode:

`$page = (int) $_GET['page'];`

WP has tools in it to manage rewrites, and it would probably be better to use those instead of .htaccess, so you can keep all your code contained in your plugin folder.  I haven't played with that yet, so here goes nothing:

This SHOULD do the same thing, but without modifying the .htaccess file.

`add_action( 'init', 'add_items_rules' );
function add_items_rules() { 
    add_rewrite_rule(
        "items/(\d*)",
        "items/?page=$matches[1]",
        "top"
    );
}`

Comment: thanks but I want to do rewrite by plugin

Comment: your last solution shows me error 404

Comment: this solution worked for me in this form: `add_rewrite_rule(
        "items/(\d*)",
        "index.php/?page_id=23&page=$matches[1]",
        "top"
    );` but now I cant access vale of `$_GET['page']` from plugin.